# Execute functions out of a Tuple in Scala

Tags: scala, function, lambda, functional-programming, tuples

I have a Tuple where I have stored anonymous functions, I want to iterate through them and execute them.

```
val functions = ((x:Int, y:Int) => x + y, (x:Int, y: Int) => x - y)
// I want to execute the anonymous functions in the Tuple
functions.productIterator.foreach(function => function)
```

Unfortunately I am not able to do

```
functions.productIterator.foreach(function => function(1, 2))
```

OR

```
functions.productIterator.foreach(_(1, 2))
```

what is the way out.

Answer (score 4):

Tuples are not meant to be iterated over.  The types get lost because each entry in a tuple is able to be a different type and so the type system just assumes `Any` (thus the `Iterator[Any]`).  So the real suggestion is that if you want to iterate, use a collection like a `Seq` or `Set`.

On the other hand, if you *know* that the tuple contains functions of a particular type, then you can bypass the type checking by casting with `asInstanceOf`, but this is **not recommended** because type checking is your friend.

```
functions.productIterator.map(_.asInstanceOf[(Int,Int)=>Int](1, 2))
// produces `Iterator(3, -1)`
```

Alternatively, have a look at HLists in [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0), which have properties of both tuples and collections.

Answer (score 1):

`productIterator` on a `Tuple` returns `Iterator[Any]` and not `Iterator[Function2[Int, Int, Int]]` as you're expecting.

Comment: Agree, how do I tackle it under such scenario; is there a way to do pattern matching and then execute the function.

Answer (score 0):

We can extract the elements of the tuple into a `Seq` while preserving type information; hence

```
Seq(functions._1, functions._2).map(_(1,2))
List(3, -1)
```